# Cannot execute certain strings

Tags: python

I have some scripts that will need a string which is unable to load in the program (or something simillar to that).

I tested it through a simple line of code:

```
print('C:\Users\MTLS\source\python\Models_2-3D models\Triangular_Prism.obj')
```

And when i launch the program, this is what displayed in the Terminal:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
PS C:\Users\MTLS\source\python> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" c:/Users/MTLS/source/python/Program_2-Test/test.py
  File "c:\Users\MTLS\source\python\Program_2-Test\test.py", line 1
    print('C:\Users\MTLS\source\python\Models_2-3D models\Triangular_Prism.obj')
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

What should i do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Use a raw string: `print(r'C:\Users\MTLS\source\python\Models_2-3D models\Triangular_Prism.obj')
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses the backslash to denote special characters. These include \n, for new lines, \r, for returns, and others.

What is happening here is that Python thinks that you are using some of these special characters when typing out your string. Therefore, you need to escape them by using `\\`. This will tell Python that you don't mean a special character, and want to type just a backslash.

Do this for each of the backslashes in your string.